# backbone.js router error in firebug

Tags: backbone.js

I'm a newbie in backbone.js and writing my first router. I have a backbone router as below,

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>My First Backbone Tutorial</title>
        <meta name="author" content="David Goodlad <david@goodlad.ca>">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/screen.css" media="screen, projection">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/fancypants.css" media="screen, projection">

        <script type="text/template" id="library-template">
            <h1> Music Library</h1>
            <ul class="albums"></ul>
        </script>

        <script type="text/template" id="album-template">
            <span class="album-title"><%= title %></span>
            <span class="artist-name"><%= artist %></span>
            <ol class="tracks">
                <% _.each(tracks, function(track) { %>
                <li><%= track.title %></li>
                <% }); %>
            </ol>
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <h1>User manager</h1>
            <hr />
            <div class="page"></div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/underscore.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/backbone.js"></script>
        <script>
            var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
                routes:{
                    "" : 'home'
                }
            });
            var router = new Router();
            router.on('route:home', function(){
                console.log("======================================")
            });
            Backbone.history.start();
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

When I load the page, I'm getting an error in firebug like

> TypeError: router.on is not a function
>      router.on('route:home', function(){

May i know what is my mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You definitely did something more than that, share some more information please. Backbone.Router extends Backbone.Events so the `on` method should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

having only the code that you pasted in a file I added Backbone.hisrory.start(); and it worked for me.
If this does not solve your issue perhaps you could share a little bit more of your code so we can take a look. I think it may be an issue of how are you adding your Backbone files and its dependencies but I cant tell for sure.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
        '' : 'home'
    }
});
var router = new Router();
router.on('route:home', function(){
    console.log("======================================")
});
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: Hi guys, I edited my question with full code and am using Backbone.js 0.5.1 version..Can anyone please help me in solving this.

Comment: I think the Jquery version that you are using its not supported by Backbone, Backbone works wirh jquery 1.7.2 or higher.